# Unity. Вкл/Выкл BoxCollider 2D у всех клонов объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Есть 2 объекта: BallRed, BallBlue которые спавнятся в игре в разных количествах
Как при каком либо условии выбрать все созданные клоны, и отключить/включить Box Collider2D ?
Например:

```
if (red){
    //Выбрать все BallRed;
    //Выключить у всех BallRed Box Collider2D;
}
else if(blue){
    //Выбрать все BallBlue;
    //Включить у всех BallBlue Box Collider2D;
}
```

Comment: можно использовать теги или маркерные компоненты

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Тег у BallRed и BallBlue один, и если поменять, придется много кода переписывать. А маркерные компоненты я не знаю как использовать и что это. Я новичек

Comment: Пустой скрипт, по которому можно найти все экземпляры, ну или если это изначально разные скритпы - можно искать по типу компонента, правда это медленно

Answer (score 0):

За спавн шаров у тебя наверняка отвечает некий скрипт-менеджер. Создай два List и добавляй в них шары, так можно будет работать сразу со всеми. Либо скрипт шаров при спавне находит этот менеджер и добавляет себя в List сам, и сам-же удаляет себя на OnDestroy, если нужно.